# Не сортирует по индексу вместе с LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql

$query = "select * from discussions where subject = '".$subject."' and type = '".$type."' ORDER BY message_id desc LIMIT $limit, $per_page";

Данный запрос не сортирует записи по уникальному индексу. Почему?
Если я убираю LIMIT, то все нормально

Comment: вставьте в вопрос результат <? var_dump($query); ?>

Comment: помогло увидел ошибку - передавал некорректный номер страницы $page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Что находится в $limit и $per_page ?
2. что находится в $subject ? Если это числовое поле - то всё ок. Если строковое - то запрос работать не будет.
3. Аналогично п.2 только с $type

Comment: Спасибо. Неправильный был $page